# if pattern in line then underline the line having pattern python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working to get `if pattern in line then underline the Entire line having pattern` but being a newbie learner i'm somehow not able to fit the trick..

Below is my file to be processed through..

```
# cat mytest.txt
All records went successful
record1
record2
All records went unsuccessful
record3
record4
All records went successful
record5
record6
```

Below what i tried but does all the lines `underlined` when condition met:

```
patt_success = False
with open("mytest.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
      if patt_success:
          if "successful" in line:
              patt_success = True
          else:
              patt_success = False
              pp = line.rstrip('\n')
              print('\033[1m' + 'pp')
          #print('\033[0m' + 'pp')
```

Below is the class order for this i'm using..

```
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
```

Desired Output:

```
# cat mytest.txt
All records went successful
----------------------------
record1
record2
All records went unsuccessful
record3
record4
All records went successful
---------------------------
record5
record6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Shell markup stays active until you cancel it, so matched lines
  should end with '\033[0m'
- The boolean patt_success is not necessary, you can handle it per line
- You should add a space in front of the word 'successful', otherwise it will also match 'unsuccessful'

Working version:

```
UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
END = '\033[0m'

with open("mytest.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
      pp = line.rstrip('\n')
      if " successful" in line:
          print(UNDERLINE + pp + END)
      else:
          print(pp)
```